# how to calculate recent n days unique rows

Tags: r, tidyverse

Say I want count recent 15 days unique id for everyday. Here is the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
set.seed(1)
eg <- tibble(day = sample(seq(ymd('2018-01-01'), length.out = 100, by = 'day'), 300, replace = T),
             id = sample(letters[1:26], 300, replace = T),
             value = rnorm(300))

eg %>% 
  group_by(day) %>% 
  summarise(uniqu_id = n_distinct(id),
            recent_15_days_unique_id = 'howto',
            day_total = sum(value))
```

The result is

```
# A tibble: 95 x 4
   day        uniqu_id recent_15_days_unique_id day_total
   <date>        <int> <chr>                        <dbl>
 1 2018-01-01        3 how                         -1.38 
 2 2018-01-02        3 how                          2.01 
 3 2018-01-03        3 how                          1.57 
 4 2018-01-04        6 how                         -1.64 
 5 2018-01-05        2 how                         -0.293
 6 2018-01-06        4 how                         -2.08
```

For the 'recent_15_days_unique_id' column, first row is to count unique id between "day-15" to "day", which is '2017-12-17' and '2018-01-01', second row is between '2017-12-18' and '2018-01-02'.It is kind like 'rollsum' function but for counting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `ungroup` and for every day, we can create a sequence of 15 days and count all the unique `id`s in that duration.

```
library(dplyr)

eg %>% 
   group_by(day) %>% 
   summarise(uniqu_id = n_distinct(id),
             day_total = sum(value)) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   rowwise() %>%
   mutate(recent_15_days_unique_id = 
    n_distinct(eg$id[eg$day %in% seq(day - 15, day, by = "1 day")]))



 #   day        uniqu_id day_total recent_15_days_unique_id
 # <date>        <int>     <dbl>                    <int>
 #1 2018-01-02        2    0.170                         2
 #2 2018-01-03        2   -0.460                         3
 #3 2018-01-04        1   -1.53                          3
 #4 2018-01-05        2    1.67                          5
 #5 2018-01-06        2    1.52                          6
 #6 2018-01-07        4   -1.62                         10
 #7 2018-01-08        2   -0.0190                       12
 #8 2018-01-09        1   -0.573                        12
 #9 2018-01-10        2   -0.220                        13
#10 2018-01-11        7   -1.73                         14
```

---

Using the same logic we can also calculate it separately using `sapply`

```
new_eg <- eg %>% 
         group_by(day) %>% 
         summarise(uniqu_id = n_distinct(id),
                   day_total = sum(value)) %>%
         ungroup()


sapply(new_eg$day, function(x) 
   n_distinct(eg$id[as.numeric(eg$day) %in% seq(x-15, x, by = "1 day")]))

#[1]  2  3  3  5  6 10 12 12 13 14 15 16 17 17 18 20 21 22 22 20 20 21 21 .....
```

Comment: just checking but is the first date, 2018-01-01, missing in the output from your first solution?  Also, for a total running sum, if you have 2 unique id's on 2018-01-02 and 2 more on 2018-01-03, shouldn't the running sum for 2018-01-03 be at least 4 rather than 3 - or have I misinterpreted?

Comment: @krads If you run OP's reproducible example you will notice there is no `day` with date `2018-01-01` it starts with `2018-02-02`. As for running sum for unique id, if date 1 has 2 unique id say 100, 200 and date 2 has other 2 unique id 200, 300, then the total unique id in that window would be only 3 (100, 200, 300) since 200 is repeated. Hope this clarifies. :)

Comment: Ah, yes, I see that.  Confusing point was in the OP's sample output he has listed 2018-01-01.  Also I see your point now in what he was trying to accomplish with his 'unique counts'.  Thanks for clarifying!